# Oracle Express: Getting ORA-12154 error when trying to connect using SQL Plus

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, oracle-xe

My computer's operating system is Windows 7 64-bit. I just downloaded and install Oracle Express 11g Windows 64-bit. During installation it ask me to set password for both the SYS and the SYSTEM database accounts which I provide as **P@ssword1**. Everything went ok during installation.

Now I want to connect using SQL Plus. So I click on *All Programs --> Oracle Database 11g Express Edition --> Run SQL Command Line* to open SQL Plus.

There I type in `connect system/P@ssword1` and press Enter key. But I get this error message: **ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

> SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jan 18 22:19:11 2017
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
>
> SQL> connect system/P@ssword1 
> ERROR: 
> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve
>   the connect identifier specified
>
> SQL>

Why I cannot connect?

Thanks

Comment: In any case, it is better not to provide the password in the connect identifier. Provide only the username and let the system prompt you for the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `P@ssword1` as the password

Can you try the following for connecting to DB instance through SQL*PLUS?

`connect system/"P@ssword1"`

The reason for Oracle to throw the error is that it treats `ssword1` (P@**ssword1**) as the connect identifier.

Comment: It worked. Thanks. So the usage of @ in passwords is kind of discouraging in Oracle?

Comment: This link should answer your query... http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/avoid-the-symbol-in-oracle-passwords/